# Solving a particular system of Diophantine equations in $n$ variables (Frobenius equations)

Tags: diophantine-equations, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

I have a particular system of linear Diophantine equations in $n$ variables for which I need to find all nonnegative integer solutions.

Specifically, they are Frobenius equations, meaning the coefficients are natural numbers and nonnegative integer solutions. The equations are:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & ... & 1\\
        1 & 2 & ... & n \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
        x_1 \\
        \vdots \\
        x_n
        \end{matrix}\right)
=\left(\begin{matrix}
        M-r\\
        M
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

n and M are fixed, and I'll need to solve for each of r=0,..., floor$\left(\frac{M(n-1)}{n}\right)$.

Ideally, I will be able to solve relatively large $M$ (as large as computation and storage allows).

I had some luck using Mathematica's built-in Frobenius equation solver to generate all solutions for the second equation and then pulling out solutions satisfying $x_1 + ... + x_n=M-r$ for each $r$. For $n=10$ (which is sufficient for my needs), I was able to solve for as high as $M=100$, but going much larger made computation time (and space) troublesome.

Is there a way to take advantage of the existence of the second equation, linearity, or some other detail that isn't being considered to solve this more efficiently?

Is solving it with $n=10, M=1000$ a pipe dream on a strong desktop computer? Would it even be attainable on more substantial hardware?

Thanks!

Comment: A little update in case anyone ever runs across the question with some interest:

n = 3, M = 1000 worked fine with the described strategy with some time.

It seems n = 10, M = 1000 is a no-go on my laptop (which isn't particularly good), but storage was the issue after running for a day despite fairly good progress, so I would conjecture it's a reasonable strategy with moderate computing resources.